# I can't get ApolloServer to return connected nodes with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I'm currently working on a project where I retrieve data from a Neo4j database using a GraphQL query. The query returns a central Company node along with its connected nodes, which can be of type Company or Person. I'm having trouble mapping the connected nodes properly in my JavaScript code.

Here's an excerpt of the code I'm using:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');
const { GraphQLJSON } = require('graphql-scalars');

const typeDefs = gql`
  scalar JSON

  type Company {
    id: ID!
    orgNo: String!
    companyName: String!
    address: String!
    city: String!
    zipCode: String!
    connectedNodes: [Node]
  }
  
    type Person {
    id: ID!
    role: String
    ZipCode: String
    Street: String
    test_id: String
    label: String
    City: String
    RoleCode: String
    Name: String
  }


  type Node {
    id: ID!
    labels: [String]
    properties: JSON
  }

  type Query {
    company(orgNo: String!): Company
  }
`;


const driver = neo4j.driver(
  'bolt://localhost:7687',
  neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password')
);

const resolvers = {
  JSON: GraphQLJSON,

  Query: {
    company: async (_, { orgNo }) => {
      const session = driver.session();
      const result = await session.run(
        `MATCH (source:Company {OrgNo: $orgNo})
        OPTIONAL MATCH path = (source)-[*1..3]-(target)
        WHERE NONE(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE rel.RoleCode IN ['REV', 'SU'])
        RETURN source, COLLECT(DISTINCT target) AS connected_nodes`,
        { orgNo }
      );
      await session.close();
      
      const companyNode = result.records[0]?.get('source')?.properties;
      if (!companyNode) return null;
      
      const connectedNodes = result.records[0]?.get('connected_nodes')?.map(record => {
        const nodeType = record && record.labels?.[0];
        const nodeProperties = record && record.properties;
        


        if (record && record.labels.includes('Company')) {
          return {
            id: record.identity?.toString() || null,
            labels: record.labels || [],
            properties: nodeProperties || {}
          };
        } else if (record && record.labels.includes('Person')) {
          return {
            id: nodeProperties && nodeProperties['test_id']?.toString() || null,
            labels: record.labels || [],
            properties: nodeProperties || {}
          };
        }
        
        
        return node;
      }) || [];
      
      
      // console.log(connectedNodes)

      const company = {
        id: companyNode && companyNode['identity']?.toString() || '',
        orgNo: companyNode && companyNode['OrgNo'] || null,
        companyName: companyNode && companyNode['CompanyName'] || null,
        address: companyNode && companyNode['Address'] || null,
        city: companyNode && companyNode['City'] || null,
        zipCode: companyNode && companyNode['ZipCode'] || ''
      };
      

      return company;
    },
  },
};




const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server running at ${url}`);
});
```

I've been able to retrieve the central Company node successfully. However, when trying to map the connected nodes in connectedNodes, I haven't been able to achieve the desired result. The console.log(connectedNodes) statement outputs an the nodes as list.

I suspect that there might be an issue with the mapping logic or how I'm accessing the properties of each connected node. I've tried various approaches, including using optional chaining (?.) and checking for the node type using conditions.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly map the connected nodes in this scenario. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Neo4j offers a javascript GraphQL library which will help you with that. See https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/introduction/. No need to write any resolvers when you use the library. Hope that works!

Comment: Otherwise check the free book which explains how to get from manual resolvers to using the library https://neo4j.com/blog/free-book-full-stack-graphql-applications/

Comment: @Thomas Wiss
Thank you for that. I got it up and running, awesome with toGraphQLTypeDefs. 31 lines of code and I got all my schema.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to pass the connectedNodes in the const const.

```
const resolvers = {
  JSON: GraphQLJSON,

  Query: {
    company: async (_, { orgNo }) => {
      const session = driver.session();
      const result = await session.run(
        `
        MATCH (source:Company {OrgNo: $orgNo})
        OPTIONAL MATCH path = (source)-[*1..3]-(target)
        WHERE NONE(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE rel.RoleCode IN ['REV', 'SU'])
        RETURN source, COLLECT(DISTINCT target) AS connected_nodes
        `,
        { orgNo }
      );
      session.close();

      const companyNode = result.records[0]?.get('source')?.properties;
      if (!companyNode) return null;

      const connectedNodes = result.records[0]?.get('connected_nodes')?.map(record => {
        const nodeType = record && record.labels?.[0];
        const nodeProperties = record && record.properties;

        return {
          id: record.identity?.toString() || null,
          labels: record.labels || [],
          properties: nodeProperties || {}
        };
      }) || [];

      const company = {
        id: companyNode && companyNode['identity']?.toString() || '',
        orgNo: companyNode && companyNode['OrgNo'] || null,
        companyName: companyNode && companyNode['CompanyName'] || null,
        address: companyNode && companyNode['Address'] || null,
        city: companyNode && companyNode['City'] || null,
        zipCode: companyNode && companyNode['ZipCode'] || '',
        connectedNodes: connectedNodes
      };

      return company;
    },
  },

  Company: {
    connectedNodes: async (parent) => parent.connectedNodes
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).